# Connection from Zapier to Podio refused

Tags: zapier, podio

First time I saw this...my client is using way less of Podio than most of my clients.  However, I cant get zapier to connect:

The app returned "You have hit the rate limit. Please wait 3600 seconds before trying again. See https://developers.podio.com/index/limits for more information. If you have a project that requires a higher rate limit c...". You have hit the rate limit. Please wait 3600 seconds before trying again. See https://developers.podio.com/index/limits for more information. If you have a project that requires a higher rate limit contact support at https://help.podio.com.

Answer (score 0):

Is this possibly a shared rate limit for all Podio users on Zapier? I'd suggest reaching out to Podio support about this. Zapier support should be able to get you the HTTP response log that displays this error for context.